# Unity returns NULL when I try to send a HTTPS request

Tags: c#, ssl, unity-game-engine, https, mono

I'm struggling to send a HTTPS request on Unity for about 3 days. I did search a lot about it and what I understand is that Mono doesn't support SSL validation. **[LOL.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2017-1-tls-1-2-still-not-working-with-net-4-6.487415/page-2#post-3627811)**

There is a solution for this on the internet. Putting this snippet code in above of HTTP request code.

```c#
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

But, unfortunately, it's not working.

I'm using the "Http Client" asset:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#!/content/79343

My code:

```c#
    public string send()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
        httpClient.GetString(new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"), (r) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(r.Data);
        });
    }
```

I would be glad If someone can help me on this. I've tried the official HTTP APIs of Unity but the result is same. Please don't suggest me to upgrade the runtime or Unity version. I'm making a Unity asset for [botdelive](https://botdelive.com) and it should work on every version of it. By the way, I don't want to use StartCoroutine/IEnumerator.

**Unity version: 2017.3.1.f1**
**Runtime version: .NET 3.5**
**Api Compatibilitiy Level: .NET 2.0 Subset**

> **PROBLEM SOLVED. BUT...** This asset does what I need but it is a closed source and contains some .DLL files. I don't trust it. :/
>   https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/rest-client-for-unity-102501

Comment: *"Please don't suggest me to upgrade the runtime or Unity version. I'm making a Unity asset for botdelive and it should work on every version of it. By the way, I don't want to use StartCoroutine/IEnumerator."* Your request is unrealistic. You either have to do that or create your own native HttpClient  plugin for every platform which supports  https. So you have to use what's already been made by Unity or make your own. It's not easy but possible. Although, it requires you know, Java, Objective-C and C++ if you decide to make your own.

Comment: I found the exact HttpClient plugin but unfortunately, it is a closed source. Instead of making my own, I will use HTTP gateway between HTTPS server and Unity. :/